# C# timeout - is mine dangerous...?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, timeout, invoke

I have created a timeout function based on things I have seen in various places but am pretty sure I am not doing it a great way! (But it does seem to work.)

I am connecting to a piece of hardware that if working connects in a few seconds but if not takes around 1 minute to timeout.  So if I can create my own timeout function I can set it at 20 seconds and save lots of time and waiting.

I have tried to make it so my timeout returns a string:

```
static string CallWithTimeout(Action action, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
    string reply = "";
    Thread threadToKill = null;
    Action wrappedAction = () =>
    {
        threadToKill = Thread.CurrentThread;
        action();
    };

    IAsyncResult result = wrappedAction.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutMilliseconds))
    {
        reply = "Connected";
        wrappedAction.EndInvoke(result);
        return reply;
    }
    else
    {
        threadToKill.Abort();
        reply = "Error";
        return reply;            
    }      
}
```

then I call it with something like :

```
string replyfromreader = CallWithTimeout(connectToHardware, 20000);
```

the `connectToHardware` is just a one liner so no need to post.

Comment: Using `Thread.Abort` is (almost) always the wrong approach. But to provide a better answer we need to know more of the behaviour the underlying API you are cancelling. Could it be allowed to continue to its normal completion even after a timeout (just ignore what it is doing while returning concurrently)?

Comment: Also you are killing a random thread pool thread: that is definitely a bad idea. If you must use `Thread.Abort` (this is an open Q) then create your own thread for it.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample in .net 3.5?

Comment: Avoiding Thread.Abort is always a good idea.   
Avoiding it on a thread you did not create is even better. 

How To Stop a Thread in .NET (and Why Thread.Abort is Evil)   
http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation

Dangers of Thread.Abort by Eric Lippert  
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/22/should-i-specify-a-timeout.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding `Thread.Abort` is always a good idea. Avoiding it on a thread you did not create is even better.

Assuming if the hardware is not working, and you want the timeout, it does not matter if `connectToHardware` is left to timeout on its own and no error/exception details are wanted, then you can use the Task Parallel Library (TPL): [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx):

```
// True => worked, False => timeout
public static bool CallWithTimeout(Action method, TimeSpan timeout) {
  Exception e;
  Task worker = Task.Factory.StartNew(method)
                    .ContineueWith(t => {
                      // Ensure any exception is observed, is no-op if no exception.
                      // Using closure to help avoid this being optimised out.
                      e = t.Exception;
                    });
  return worker.Wait(timeout);
}
```

(If the passed `Action` could interact with a passed `CancellationToken` this could be made cleaner, allowing the underlying method to fail quickly on timeout.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  am trying this now.  It doesn't like this bit though : .ContinueWith(t => {, it says I am re declaring the variable 't'...

Comment: Just changed it for another letter. Works great.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kiquenet DIY with a thread and [`Thread.Join(timeout)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: @Kiquenet If you cannot work this out yourself (hint: body of task becomes body of thread) then I suggest you stay away from threads where it is very easy to shoot yourself in the foot. (Also this is a workaround for bad driver/hardware that doesn't handle failure sensibly: not a general "perform action with timeout" mechanism.)

Answer (score 1):

It's okayish as far as .NET state is concerned.  You won't call EndInvoke(), that leaks resources for 10 minutes, the default lifetime of remoted objects.

In a case like this, calling Thread.Abort() has a *very* small chance of succeeding.  A managed thread needs to be in an alertable wait state to be abortable, it just never is when the thread is buried deep inside native code that ultimately waits for some device driver call to complete.

Leaving the CLR in a state where it keeps trying to abort a thread and never succeeds is not particularly pleasant, not something I've ever tried on purpose so no real idea what the side-effects are.  It does however mean that your code will block on the Abort() method call so you still haven't fixed the problem.  The best thing to do is therefore to *not* abort the thread but just abandon it.  Setting a flag that marks the device dead so you don't try to do this ever again.

If you want to continue running your program, even without the device being in a usable state, and you want to provide a way to recover from the problem then you'll need an entirely different approach.  You'll need to put the device related code in a separate process.  Which you can then Kill() when the device is unresponsive, relying on Windows to clean up the shrapnel.  Interop with that process using a low-level mechanism like named pipes or sockets is best so you can recover from the disconnect fairly easily.